# In Eclipse RCP, how to prevent a PartStack from being destroyed when it becomes empty

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a Sash containing two PartStacks. Each PartStack contains a Part.
When moving a Part from the first PartStack to the second PartStack, the first PartStack becomes empty. **It is then destroyed from the Model.** (I checked this using the LiveEditor plugin.)

What I would expect is the PartStack to remain where it is, and just be empty:

```
=> Before the move:

  Sash
    PartStack1
      Part1
    PartStack2
      Part2

=> After the move:

  Sash
    PartStack1
      (empty)
    PartStack2
      Part2
      Part1
```

Any idea how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the tag 'NoAutoCollapse' to the part stack:

[image]

Comment: Ahh! Thank you. I looked for an exhaustive list of tags and it seems IPresentationEngine is it: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fe4%2Fui%2Fworkbench%2FIPresentationEngine.html . It would be great if the Model editor in Eclipse had a little tickbox to do this (similarly to the "Closeable" tickbox for Part).